# Слово "іногородній": яке походження та синоніми?

Tags: переклад, етимологія, from-russian

Часто можна натрапити на оголошення, в яких є речення на кшталт *"Іногороднім надаємо житло"*. Наскільки я розумію, а [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/inoghorodnij) підтверджує, це слово означає "особа не з цього міста".

Можливо, що ми успішно скопіювали його з російського *иногородний*, яке [утворене](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) від слів *иной* і *город*. Проте, коли це слово прийшло в українську мову, знайти мені не вдалося. Наприклад, [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/inoghorodnij) та [ще один](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9) ресурс подають однаковий приклад (уривок з газети 1961 року):

> Три таксі виявились іногородніми. Але чотири все-таки були нашими, київськими.

Навіть існує "[Іногородній факультет"](http://vnz.org.ua/vnz/ar-krym/346-simferopolskyj-inogorodnij-fakultet-poltavskogo-universytetu-ekonomiky-i-torgivli), що там вивчають - повна загадка.

Не одному мені здається, що даний прикметник виглядає не органічно в українській мові, тому користувачі "Словотвору" [намагалися](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/inohorodnii) підібрати йому відповідник. Жодний з них, на мою думку, не відображає точного значення даного слова, адже, наприклад, слова *нетутешній* та *немісцевий* можна використати і для позначення людини з іншої частини міста, або не з цього села, області, країни і т.ін.

Чи проводились дослідження даної проблеми?

**Який відповідник якнайкраще передає смисл слова *іногородній*?**

Comment: Ймовірно, слово прийшло з російської (попри існування го́рода і в українській), точно скопіювавши російський аналог (я б тут більше звернув увагу не на іно-, а на вживання прикметника в іменниковій ролі). Якщо українська мова має кращий варіант, то незрозуміло, чому він маловідомий (адже го́род спокійно пішов у забуття як російськоподібний архаїзм).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В українській є декілька усталених слів з префіксом `іно-`: напр., *іноземець* (еквівалент *"чужоземець"*), *інопланетянин* (еквівалент *"прибулець"*).

З іншого боку, є і кілька слів з префіксом `іншо-`: напр., *іншомовний*.

Тому не можна сказати, що префікс `іно-` або `іншо-` зовсім непридатні до вжитку.

Окремо варто зазначити, що [*город*](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghorod) у значенні «місто» є рідко вживаним. Тому будь-яке слово, яке закінчується на `-городній` може бути сприйняте як «з горо́ду, садибної ділянки».

Стосовно спроб добрати відповідник на "Словотворі", варто зауважити, що усі запропоновані варіанти (окрім, спірно, варіанту *нетутешній*) базуються на теоретичних побудовах, які, на мою думку, досить часто призводять до утворення неоковирних словесних покручів, якими важко користуватися. :-)

Тому, можливо, варто або користатися словом **нетутешній**, або словосполученням **з іншого міста**.

---

Стосовно «Іногороднього факультету», зауважте: йдеться про факультет вишу, який знаходиться у іншому місті. [У даному випадку](http://vnz.org.ua/vnz/ar-krym/346-simferopolskyj-inogorodnij-fakultet-poltavskogo-universytetu-ekonomiky-i-torgivli), це **Сімферопольський** факультет вишу, який, взагалі-то, знаходиться **у Полтаві**.
Для таких випадків в українській мові є слово **філія/філіал**.
Наприклад: [Філія Університету Драгоманова в Празі](http://vstup.info/2012/i2012i1308.html).

Answer (score 4):

Походження <sub>рос.</sub> *иногородний*, судячи з джерел, є кубанським. До прикладу, словник Ожегова подає [*иногородний*](http://slovarozhegova.ru/word.php?wordid=9940):

> О крестьянах казачьих областей до 1917 г.: не принадлежащий к казачьему сословию. Казаки иногородние (сущ.)

В словнику Фасмера <sub>рос.</sub> [*русопет*](https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D1%80/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82):

> русопёт «иногородний, не казак», презрит., курск., донск

Тобто йдеться про <sub>рос.</sub> [городових казаків](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8) (не плутати з [реєстровими козаками](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%94%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)), а *иногородний* — той, хто до них не належить.

Можу допустити, що згодом значення цього терміну було перенесено на  *місто* взагалі (<sub>рос.</sub> *город*).

---

В українському словнику 1930 року *іногородній* [не зафіксовано](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> Иногородний (о кореспонденте) – іномі́ський, з і́ншою мі́ста.

Голова уряду Кубанської Народної Республіки Василь Іваніс у своїх спогадах «[Стежками життя](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=bMvUAAAAMAAJ&q=%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9&dq=%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiww_36wa3SAhUCEpoKHTxxA5sQ6AEILTAE)» <sub>(на жаль, повний текст не вдалося дістати)</sub> вживає *іногородні*, але також і ***навгородні***:

[image: іногородні — навгородні]

---

Якщо говорити про відповідники, які вже присутні в українській мові, найближчим (і вдалішим) НМД є [*прихожий*](http://sum.in.ua/s/prykhozhyj):

> Той, хто прийшов звідкись; немісцева, чужа людина

З точки зору *осідлих*, *вкорінених*, такі люди *приходять* з інших місць (аналог <sub>рос.</sub> "*понаехали тут*", але без негативного відтінку).

Приклад вживання:

> Прихожим студентам надаємо гуртожиток безкоштовно.
>   Прихожі робітники забезпечуються житлом.

Втім, ніхто не заважає вживати це слово і як іменник (на кшталт *перехожі*):

> Прихожим надаємо гуртожиток безкоштовно.
>   Прихожі забезпечуються житлом.

Хоча перший варіянт буде допомагати тим, хто звик до *іногородній*.

Одночасно є вирази, де краще вживати саме *нетутешній*:

> Три таксі виявились нетутешніми. Але чотири все-таки були нашими, київськими.